# Why is chat kick first ask never?

Tags: discussion, chat

In general mods and RO's for main chat rooms are kick-first ask never. Why is that? It is easy to take messages wrong and kicking before asking clarification is faulty.

## EDIT:

I posted this late at night. It was a  mistake  I understand now that I am awake sorry for wasting your time

Comment: I'm interested in the context of your question. I find it difficult to believe their were *no* warnings.

Comment: @Andy I posted TWO messages using caps over an hour

Comment: [The warning](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39947431#39947431) @Andy

Comment: Why is Meta ask first, research never?

Comment: @shog last I checked that was after the fact

Comment: After which fact? It was before you asked this question, @Christopher. So you ignored the specific guidance from a room owner and came here asking a misleading question with zero context. You wanna construct a timeline, be my guest - then put it in your question instead of expecting everyone here to play detective to answer your question. Or just **learn to take a hint** instead of wasting everyone's time with trivial nonsense.

Comment: @Shog9 sorry about the waste of time, I made this question while I was annoyed and tired. I wasn't thinking straight at the time of kick/this post. Anways thats for you time

Comment: Np; it happens.

Comment: @Shog9 are you always on or are you just my responsible alternate ego?

Comment: Little bit of both

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, people tend to not like it when someone posts ALL IN CAPS

REPEATEDLY

IN MULTIPLE MESSAGES

FOR NO REASON.

But, hey, maybe in some rooms - like, say, The Nineteenth Byte - they absolutely love all them caps.

Only way to find out is to try it, & see if you get kicked.

So... What'd you learn?

Comment: (I did send a caps message an hour earlier and again no warning) I sent one message with partial caps. Then got 30 min kick for humorously saying I would stop (not using caps). See the confusion?

Comment: I also had 2 trashed messages that were legitimate messages but part of a conversation that ended trashed to clear up the room.

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ Did you read the read the [Nineteenth Byte rules](https://ppcg.github.io/chatiquette/)? They're pretty darn strict: *If your messages are removed, or you are kicked or suspended, please reflect on the cause and make an effort to not violate the chatiquette in the future. If, after reflection, you believe a room owner action was inappropriate, please feel free to bring it up with the other room owners or on Meta for review.*

Comment: fully CAPS... this post is rude or offensive

Answer (score 9):

[Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300758/215590) is exactly right. Pay particular attention to that last question:

> So...What'd you learn?

Based on your [own messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39947603#39947603), it almost seems like the answer is "not much":

> Yeah I was kicked 3 times today 2 for caps
>
> And I have used caps in 2 messages today
>
> tbh idk know why I was kicked the 2nd time

You were warned via the [pinned guidelines](https://ppcg.github.io/chatiquette/) in the room description. You were [warned](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39947431#39947431) via a room owner. ([Twice](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39947374#39947374)). You were [warned](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39947387#39947387) via a user in the room that your "next time" threat is still inappropriate. That's four different attempts by the community to get you to understand that type of discourse they wish to have in that room.

Another mod also [nicely informed you](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39947760#39947760), in the context of your request for granting a 1 rep user the ability to chat, that:

> Talking in chat is a privilege and must be earned.

Chat is a privilege. Chat is also one of those privileges that can be revoked. You were warned not to use all caps. You ignored that warning, repeatedly. Thus, you were kicked.

Now, take a minute and think about what happened next. You've been kicked. Your first thought at this point should be to determine what behavior *you* need to change. Kicking isn't something that is done lightly. Repeated kicks will raise a moderator flag, so abuse of the feature can be caught pretty quickly.

Room owners work hard to keep their chat rooms on topic - whatever the topic of the room is. They work with the community that frequents the room to establish rules and they work to enforce those rules, if needed. It's not surprising at all that they will use the tools they've been given to handle disruptions.

---

My suggestion for you, in the future, is to remain professional. Caps (the text equivalent of shouting) isn't considered professional in the work place. Maintain your professionalism and contribute to the conversation. That will go a long way to improving your experiences in chat.

Comment: I get your points and btw 2 of those were after I was kicked the third time

Comment: And I understand now why I was kicked (but not the third time that one I am not going to ask however). I did apologize to meta and to TNB about this issue